# Power BI : trouble with DAX

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax

I work on Power BI and I have trouble to calculate what I want.

I calculated the indicator Valorisation (an amount of euro) who varies every day. The following provides an overview with a filter on the date (between 26/06/2021 and 30/06/2021) :

| Date | Valorisation |
| --- | --- |
| 26/06/2021 | 988 |
| 27/06/2021 | 845 |
| 28/06/2021 | 802 |
| 29/06/2021 | 720 |
| 30/06/2021 | 699 |

I would like to add a third column which contains uniquely the value of the Valorisation of the first date.

Example 1 :
With a filter on the date between 26/06/2021 and 30/06/2021, I would like that :

| Date | Valorisation | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26/06/2021 | 988 | 988 |
| 27/06/2021 | 845 | 988 |
| 28/06/2021 | 802 | 988 |
| 29/06/2021 | 720 | 988 |
| 30/06/2021 | 699 | 988 |

Example 2 :
With a filter on the date between 27/06/2021 and 30/06/2021, I would like that :

| Date | Valorisation | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27/06/2021 | 845 | 845 |
| 28/06/2021 | 802 | 845 |
| 29/06/2021 | 720 | 845 |
| 30/06/2021 | 699 | 845 |

I don't manage to create the measure NewColumn. I tried several things without success like that :

```
NewColumn = 
CALCULATE(
       [Valorisation Stock PVTTC N],
       DATESBETWEEN( Calendrier[DAT_REF],min(Calendrier[DAT_REF]),min(Calendrier[DAT_REF]) )
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try something as below-

```
NewColumn = 

var selected_min_date = MIN(table_name[Date])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    sum[Valorisation],
    FILTER(
        ALL(table_name),
        table_name[Date] = selected_min_date 
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I tried your code but it doesn't work. The code does the same thing that [Valorisation Stock PVTTC N] simply.

Comment: I thought [Valorisation Stock PVTTC N] is your column name. If not, only use the column name as I edited the answer.

Comment: I adapted your code like that and it worked :


NewColumn = 

var selected_min_date = CALCULATE(MIN(Calendrier[DAT_REF]),ALLSELECTED(Calendrier[DAT_REF]))

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Valorisation Stock PVTTC N],
    FILTER(
        ALL(Calendrier),
        Calendrier[DAT_REF] = selected_min_date 
    )
)

Comment: @aloux You should accept or put an upvote to the answer guide you towards the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code of mkRabbani and it worked ! Thanks !
The code :

```
NewColumn = 

var selected_min_date = CALCULATE(MIN(Calendrier[DAT_REF]),ALLSELECTED(Calendrier[DAT_REF]))

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Valorisation Stock PVTTC N],
    FILTER(
        ALL(Calendrier),
        Calendrier[DAT_REF] = selected_min_date 
    )
)
```

Comment: You should accept or put an upvote to the answer guide you towards the solution :)